# Controlling volume on iOS with QML

Tags: ios, qt, qml, mpvolumeview

I'm building a `QML` application that will play back audio. Ideally I'd like to display the current volume to the user as well as give them a slider to change the volume.

On `iOS` the only way to control volume graphically is with `MPVolumeView`. Is there a way to show an `MPVolumeView` from within a `QML` UI?

Comment: Do you want to control the “system volume” (equivalent to using hardware buttons) or only your own player’s volume only? The latter can be controlled e.g. by controlling the media player’s volume property (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#volume-prop) with a slider.

Comment: I'd like to control the system volume, hence the use of `MPVolumeView`.